# How come Docker Host & check_mk agent fail to addrress port 6556?

Tags: docker, firewalld, check-mk

I have Ubuntu 16.04 host and installed `check_mk agent` on it & all was ok. Then I installed `docker` on it and now I can not hit port 6556 and `check_mk checks` are failing too. I tried per docker KB but no luck - Add iptables policies before Docker’s rules. How to fix this?

Message:

> All of Docker’s iptables rules are added to the DOCKER chain. Do not manipulate this table manually. If you need to add rules which load before Docker’s rules, add them to the DOCKER-USER chain. These rules are loaded before any rules Docker creates automatically.

I've tried:

```
sudo iptables -I DOCKER-USER -p tcp --dport 6556 -m conntrack --ctstate     NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Did you try to temporarily disable your firewall to make sure the firewall is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

All i did is re-installed the agent & it worked well , thanks

Comment: Reviewers/Flaggers - Stop flagging/accept "Looks Okay" because this is a self commented answer and not a coding solution; this way it rids itself from the SO " unsolved questions queue". (End of Review).